# A possible proof that the operation among cosets is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

If G is a group and N is a normal subgroup of G, then the operation on G/N is well defined. Is the following a possible proof?

Since N is normal in G, abN=abNN=aNbN=a'Nb'N=a'b'NN=a'b'N if aN=a'N and bN=b'N.

There are other proofs, but isn't it good enough? It is relatively easy to prove that G/N is actually a group after showing the well-definedness. There can be a similar argument in a quotient ring.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine. It even suffices (why?) to note that the complex product of two cosets $aN$ and $bN$ is again a coset; this is the first half of your calculation: $aNbN=abNN=abN$.